# Header-Menu bar background-color

Tags: wordpress, header, background-color

I cant find the option to change the header primary background color from white to black, and the menu links from white to black.
Can anyone help?
[link to site](http://www.markitonline.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You could edit the `background-color` attribute in the `.color-overlay` class directly in the according `.css` file, if there is really no option by default.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that there will be a color setting into your theme options from the wp-admin section. And you need to check there the options there will be a header setting.
if you want from coding part please add CSS rule below into  your theme style.css

```
  #menu-main-menu li a {
  color: #fff;
}

.content.top.style-none {
  background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

if this code does not work then use !important CSS another rule.
After that, it will look like this

[image]

Comment: did you checking theme options from wp-admin